# Easiest way to write Avery 11137 template

Tags: tables, positioning, margins

Trying to get a template to work for the [Avery 11137 label template](http://www.avery.com/avery/en_us/Templates-%26-Software/Templates/Labels/File-Folder-Labels/Hanging-Folder-Insert-11137_Microsoft-Word.htm?N=4294963715&refchannel=71f4379e6fa72210VgnVCM1000002118140aRCRD) and it is exceedingly harder than one would think because the geniuses over at Avery put it on an 8.5x7 page and, although it is not impossible to print on 8.5x7 paper, it is the closest thing to impossible without trying to question relativistic physics.

[image]

So what I want to do instead is print as if it was 8.5x11 and laugh as the printer gets 7 inches in and realizes there are 4 inches missing =D

My initial thought was to use tables like so, generate the output to make sure it works, then remove the borders. But I have to make sure it fits the following margins:

- 1 inch from top
- 0.75 inches from right
- 0.75 inches from left
- Row width of 3.5 inches
- Tow height of 0.5 inches

**Minimal working example:**

EDIT I included `p{3in}` to control the width of the columns

```
\documentclass{report}

\newcommand{\labelA}{Mastercard}
\newcommand{\labelB}{Visa}
\newcommand{\labelC}{AMEX}
\newcommand{\labelD}{}
\newcommand{\labelE}{}
\newcommand{\labelF}{}
\newcommand{\labelG}{}
\newcommand{\labelH}{}
\newcommand{\labelI}{}
\newcommand{\labelJ}{}
\newcommand{\labelK}{}
\newcommand{\labelL}{}
\newcommand{\labelM}{}
\newcommand{\labelN}{}
\newcommand{\labelO}{}
\newcommand{\labelP}{}
\newcommand{\labelQ}{}
\newcommand{\labelR}{}
\newcommand{\labelS}{}
\newcommand{\labelT}{}
\newcommand{\labelU}{}
\newcommand{\labelV}{}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ |p{3in}| p{3in}| }
  \hline                       
  \labelA & \labelB \\
  \hline                       
  \labelC & \labelD \\
  \hline                       
  \labelE & \labelF \\
  \hline                       
  \labelG & \labelH \\
  \hline                       
  \labelI & \labelJ \\
  \hline                       
  \labelK & \labelL \\
  \hline                       
  \labelM & \labelN \\
  \hline                       
  \labelO & \labelP \\
  \hline                       
  \labelQ & \labelR \\
  \hline                       
  \labelS & \labelT \\
  \hline                       
  \labelU & \labelV \\
  \hline  
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

%

How do I achieve this with tables? Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 2):

I cannot tell if this is quite right without printing and I don't have any letter size paper. However, something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paper=letterpaper,layoutwidth=8.5in,layoutheight=7in,landscape]{geometry}% this says the paper is letterpaper but the layout should be 8.5x7
\usepackage[newdimens]{labels}% let the package do the work...
\LabelCols=2
\LabelRows=10
\LeftPageMargin=0.75in
\RightPageMargin=0.75in
\TopPageMargin=1in
\BottomPageMargin=3.5in
\InterLabelColumn=0mm% adjust as required
\InterLabelRow=0mm
\RightLabelBorder=5mm% adjust to taste
\LeftLabelBorder=5mm
\TopLabelBorder=5mm
\BottomLabelBorder=5mm

\LabelGridtrue %turn on to line stuff up; off to process final version
\numberoflabels=20% set to 1 when you fill in the individual labels - this will just repeat 1 instance 20 times to show the layout.

\begin{document}

\genericlabel{%
        \begin{minipage}{3.25in}% adjust as desired
          Label Text
        \end{minipage}
}

\end{document}
```

[image: labels]